# Как изменять из админки фон сайдбара для страницы wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно сделать возможность при создании новой страницы, назначать цвет фона сайдбара для этой страницы в отдельности, а не для всех страниц. Как это сделать? Хотя бы идеи...

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить дополнительное поле к странице (вот тут можно почитать http://wp-kama.ru/function/add_meta_box), в которое заносить цвет для вашего сайдбара, а потом в коде отлавливать это значение.